Expression for closest to zero value
I want to display the closest value to zero from a field in an attribute table from a QGIS layout without having to create a new field. Is it possible?

By "closest value to zero" do you mean minimum or lowest value ? do you have both positive and negative value ? could you share a sample of value and tell us witch one should be displayed as an exemple ?

by closest to zero I mean both positive or negative, so the absolute value. The sample are the results of the correlation of to parametres so the results go from 1 to -1. At the layout I want to add an attribute table that displays both the maximum and minimum (the two values with a strongest correlation closer to 1 and -1) and the one with less correlation which is the value closest to 0

Try this expression, I think it should work. It shouldn't matter if the value is positive or negative. The only requirement is that your field is integer or decimal (i.e. not a string).
if (array_contains(array_agg("YourFieldName"), array_min(array_agg(abs("YourFieldName"))))
,array_min(array_agg(abs("YourFieldName")))
,-abs(array_min(array_agg(abs("YourFieldName")))))

Basically, it checks if the smallest absolute value is in the field and returns that as the answer if it is. If it isn't, then it returns the reverse of that value.
Obviously replace YourFieldName with whatever your field is called.
